# Can I locate records in SQL table by add date?

Tags: sql, ssms

Basically I'm looking for an "undo" button but barring that -- I just added 50,000 or so records to a SQL table (SSMS).  I shouldn't have.  The easiest way to delete them would be if I could say "delete all records added to the table today".  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any kind of column like `created_at`?

Comment: depends on the table structure. like if you got a createdon etc type field.

Comment: or if you have an active backup plan, you can always restore.

Comment: Also if you know the source data...I mean the data what you have inserted, try to querying that data..once identified, delete them. otherwise... no you can't.

Answer (score 1):

If your table has some auto_increment key  you can   do the following

```
DELETE FROM tbl where id IN (select top 50000 id from tbl order by id desc )
```

This will delete last 50,000 records if you have auto_increment  key

Answer (score 0):

Table might have created/insert timestamp/date fields

Table might have inserted/created by field which will have your user ID

There might be backups of these tables, check with DBA

Data itself might have something to distinguish like one field starting with a particular word

Get value of unique key from your input data and query based on that

Make sure you are validating records before deleting